# Network Tracing for http requests

Tags: http, networking, network-programming

There is a issue raised by one of our client who is using our Rest based API that whenever he is sending a post request to our server without AcceptEncoding http header but he is getting Compressed content in return. I checked the IIS logs on our API server which addressed his request and the request  received on the server has come with a Accept-Encoding(http header) as set to gzip. In between the client machine and our server sits intermediaries(proxies) and load balancer. which network tracing tool should I use for investigating as to where this http header is getting added.

Comment: You can first get a list of the proxies crossed by the request looking at the `Via` header of your client request. Maybe there is a comment from the proxy that added the `Accept-Encoding` header.

Comment: Also, you can avoid payload transformation by adding `Cache-Control: no-transform` to the request headers (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10369679/do-http-proxy-servers-modify-request-packets)).

Comment: @Jeff Thanks a lot for pointing me in right direction, cache-control: no-transform does work for me, please could you post your answer in the answer section so that I can accept the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution to avoid an HTTP message to be compressed is to add `Cache-Control: no-transform` to the request headers to avoid payload alteration by proxies as stated in [RFC 7234 section 5.2.1.6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.2.1).

Also, `Via` header may contain useful comments that can help when looking for what did each proxy add to the request.