# Golang net/http/transport proxy CONNECT method header supporting

Tags: go

Golang's package net/http/transport can automatic setup `Proxy-Authorization` header in

```
func (t *Transport) dialConn(ctx context.Context, cm connectMethod) (*persistConn, error)
```

like

```
proxyURL, _ := url.Parse("http://username:password@example.com")
client      := http.Client{Transport: &http.Transport{Proxy:http.ProxyURL(proxyURL)}}
```

But I need submit X-Header to proxy server. How Can I custom transport CONNECT method request header?

[net/http/transport](https://golang.org/src/net/http/transport.go)

Answer (score 1):

`http.Transport` [has a function](https://go.googlesource.com/go/+/refs/heads/master/src/net/http/transport.go#253) which allows you to set some additional headers which will be sent during `CONNECT`.

Example:

```
var client http.Client
client.Transport = &http.Transport{
    Proxy: http.ProxyURL(myProxy),
    GetProxyConnectHeader: func(ctx context.Context, proxyURL *url.URL, target string) (http.Header, error) {
        return http.Header{"My-Custom-Header": []string{"My-Custom-Value"}}, nil
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

```
// ...
request, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://www.google.com", nil)
if err != nil {
  // do something
}
// add header here.
request.Header.Add("X-Header", "xxx")

response, err := client.Do(request)
if err != nil {
  // do something
}
// ...
```

Comment: This will not work, because `request.Header` will won't setup to **CONNECT**  request.

Comment: I think proxy server can't 'see' the request header when you are using `CONNECT`, check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10369679/do-http-proxy-servers-modify-request-packets